# Create and Download xlsx excel sheet in asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i am new with asp.net mvc4. I just want to create and download xlsx excel sheet in ASP.Net in MVC4. i searched much but i got nothing beneficial so an any one give me a piece of code to create and download xlsx file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You would need a third party component to do that like [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/.net/excel-component.aspx), or possible through Office automation (which means you have to have a license for that).  A tool is essentially your option.  If you are OK with CSV, you can use this technique: [Export gridview data into CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674555/export-gridview-data-into-csv-file)